# DML Field_Integrity_Exception when trying to update the HTML value on Email Templates

Tags: apex, email-template

I am using a 3rd party translation service to translate emails per the business requirement. When I get the returned HTML value I create a record using the following syntax:

```
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) data.get('results');
        String content = (String) results.get('content');
        Integer projectIdInteger = (Integer) results.get('project_id');
        String projectId = String.valueOf(projectIdInteger);
        String fileType = (String) results.get('file_mime');
        Blob decodedContent = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content);
        String output = decodedContent.toString();

        if (fileType == 'text/html') {
          //create new email template
          EmailTemplate translatedEmail = new EmailTemplate();
          translatedEmail.Name = 'OHT_Translated_Test_French';
          translatedEmail.Subject = 'this is a test';
          translatedEmail.HtmlValue = output;
          translatedEmail.UiType = 'SFX';
          translatedEmail.TemplateType = 'custom';
          translatedEmail.FolderId = '00lr0000000OYZ1AAO';
          System.debug('this is the FOLDERID id' + translatedEmail.FolderId);
          System.debug('this is the html' + translatedEmail.HtmlValue);
          insert translatedEmail;
      }
```

I have received the following error:

````
"common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The syntax for this field is incorrect: inline@718f7be7:8:32: found: '\u200b'\n            {{{Organization.Name\u200b\u200b}}}<\/div>\n  ```
````

HTML Value:
[image]

Things I have tried:

1. Used the escapeHtml4() method on the string `output`
2. Used the unescapeHtml4() method on the string `output`

Comment: N.B. `u200b` is a zero-width space character which does not look helpful here - perhaps you can use `replace()` to get rid of these before inserting

Answer (score 0):

@cropredy was correct. I was able to use the following regex syntax to remove the white spaces `output.replaceAll('[\\p{Cf}]', '');`